# Web SSO with external or partner applications

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Refer to below image ([source](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/)), I understand how SSO setup works within in enterprise where an auth server acts as centralized IdP for the organization.

[image]

My question is how does it work with external or partner app (say domain4.com) whose users are not known to the auth server (Let's assume it is Azure AD). Appreciate if someone can confirm my understanding of both the scenarios.

Scenario 1) domain4.com as SP i.e. domain1.com user tries to access domain4.com app via SSO 
Assuming domain4.com is configured as trusted app in Azure AD with SSO (SAML or OpenIDC), it allows domain1.com user to access domain4.com.

Scenario 2) domain1.com as SP i.e. domain4.com user tries to access domain1.com app via SSO 
It can be done only if domain1.com is registered with domain4.com because it is domain4.com's user which is trying to access and only domain4.com's IdP can validate it. Is there any possible way? I came across [external identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/) but did not understand it well.

Comment: Working on this and will post the findings

Answer (score 0):

As you aware the single sign on means you don't have to sign in to every application you use. Single credentials will be used for all the applications.

Identity provider and service provider where an identity provider is a trusted provider that lets you use single sign-on (SSO) to access other websites. A service provider is a website that hosts apps.  IF a user wants to access the app hosted in domain4.com then they domain4.com will be the service provider.  There are two types of sign in IDP initiated sign on where the sign-on is initiated by the IDP side user end. SP Initiated sign-on where the sign-on is initiated by the application then the request will go the IDP end (Azure).

In order to get clear detailed about single sign on kindly check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on).

If you have any further queries kindly let me know